# Register ILoggerFactory in DryIoc container

Tags: logging, xamarin.forms, prism, dryioc

I want to use Microsoft.Extensions.Logging with a DryIoc container.

The default way is to register the factory as an instance, inject it and create a logger:

```
ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory().AddDebug();
container.RegisterInstance(loggerFactory);

// inject factory in constructor
public MyService(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory){
 this.logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<MyService>()

 this.logger.LogInformation("Logger created");
}
```

But I want a more ASP.NET Core like behavior, where the Logger is directly injected:

```
// inject logger in constructor
public MyService(ILogger<MyService> logger){
 this.logger = logger;

 this.logger.LogInformation("Logger created");
}
```

So I need to create an Instance of the ILoggerFactory due to some configuration, and the ILogger<> Interface must be registered in the container using the "CreateLogger" Method when requested.

I tried using registration with a factory method from https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc/wiki/SelectConstructorOrFactoryMethod without any success.

Ended up with something like this, but the generic in CreateLogger<> is missing:

```
container.Register(typeof(ILogger<>), made: Made.Of(() => loggerFactory.CreateLogger<>()));
```

Maybe anyone can help.

**Edit**

You have to do this for getting the correct factory method:

```
var loggerFactoryMethod = typeof(LoggerFactoryExtensions).GetMethod("CreateLogger", new Type[] { typeof(ILoggerFactory) });
```

I've created and updated a working sample of this using Xamarin.Forms (with Prism and DryIoc) at [github.com/dernippel/PrismNetCoreLoggingApp](https://github.com/dernippel/PrismNetCoreLoggingApp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the full working example based on **sample** interfaces and classes.
Live code to play is [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GE2Dp2).

```
using System;
using DryIoc;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {   
        var container = new Container();

        // note usage of UseInstance instead of obsolete RegisterInstance
        container.UseInstance(new LoggerFactory()); 

        var loggerFactoryMethod = typeof(LoggerFactory).GetMethod("CreateLogger");

        container.Register(typeof(ILogger<>), made: Made.Of(
            req => loggerFactoryMethod.MakeGenericMethod(req.Parent.ImplementationType),
            ServiceInfo.Of<LoggerFactory>()));

        container.Register<MyService>();

        container.Resolve<MyService>();
    }

    class MyService 
    {   
        public MyService(ILogger<MyService> logger) { logger.Log("Hey!"); }
    }

    interface ILogger<T> 
    {
        void Log(string msg);
    }

    class ConsoleLogger<T> : ILogger<T>
    {
        public void Log(string msg) { Console.WriteLine(typeof(T) + ": " + msg); }
    }

    class LoggerFactory 
    {
        public ILogger<T> CreateLogger<T>() { return new ConsoleLogger<T>(); }
    }
}
```

### Update for static LoggerFactoryExtensions

For the static method the setup is more simple, you don't need to specify a factory instance via `ServiceInfo.Of<LoggerFactory>()`, it will be injected as any other parameter.

Here is the changes ([live sample is updated](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GE2Dp2)):

```
    var loggerFactoryMethod = typeof(LoggerFactoryExtensions).GetMethod("CreateLogger");

    container.Register(typeof(ILogger<>), made: Made.Of(
        req => loggerFactoryMethod.MakeGenericMethod(req.Parent.ImplementationType)));
```

Given the extensions:

```
public static class LoggerFactoryExtensions
{
    public static ILogger<T> CreateLogger<T>(this LoggerFactory f) { return new ConsoleLogger<T>(); }
}
```

Comment: This looks pretty good but in fact I'm on a Xamarin.Forms Prism App and using the Interfaces of Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions and DryIoc 2.12.6. On UWP I get an 'System.ArgumentNullException' without any conrete location. On Android I get an "System.InvalidOperationException: not a generic method definition" in App.xaml.cs:61. I could not test on iOS. I have created a simple sample at [github/dernippel/PrismNetCoreLoggingApp](https://github.com/dernippel/PrismNetCoreLoggingApp) for further investigation.

Comment: Check that `typeof(LoggerFactory).GetMethod("CreateLogger")` returns not null.

Comment: I checked that. `typeof(LoggerFactory).GetMethod("CreateLogger")` is not null, it's `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger CreateLogger(System.String)` on both platforms (UWP and Android).

Comment: There seems to be multiple Methods: 1. `CreateLogger(string categoryName):ILogger`, 2. `CreateLogger(this IloggerFactory factory):ILogger<T>` and 3. `CreateLogger(this ILoggerFactory factory, Type type):ILogger`. I guess the 2nd one is the right one, but GetMethod returns the first one.

Comment: The problem is now that `CreateLogger<T>`is a static extension method (`public static Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<T> CreateLogger<T>(this Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory factory)
    Member of Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFactoryExtensions`). I was able to get that method via `var loggerFactoryExtensionMethod = typeof(LoggerFactoryExtensions).GetMethod("CreateLogger",new Type[] { typeof(ILoggerFactory) });` but using it will cause a `DryIoc.ContainerException: Factory instance provided Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFactory But factory method is static`.

Comment: I have added example with the static extension method

Comment: There is another overload of `CreateLogger` in `LoggerFactoryExtensions` so i had to use `var loggerFactoryMethod = typeof(LoggerFactoryExtensions).GetMethod("CreateLogger", new Type[] { typeof(ILoggerFactory) });` for getting the correct one. With that change everything is working now. I will update my Sample-Repo too. Thanks!

Comment: Great, than accept my answer, so that others may quickly find a working solution.